# como puedo vaciar un Arraylist y actualizar el adapter dinamicamente

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un ArrayList que guarda una lista de objetos en la memoria interna, 
esos objetos se pueden exportar al almacenamiento externo mediante un dialogo con dos opciones una es conservando los registros en la memoria interna y la otra es sin conservar los registros, la primera opción funciona bien, con la segunda tengo el problema, exporto los registros pero no se eliminan.
probé utilizar: lista.clear(), lista.removeAll() para limpiar la lista y no funciono, probé eliminar el archivo creado datos.txt y actualizar el fragment para que se recargue y me da error al intentar cargar nuevos registros, y también probe: adapter.clear(), o adapter.notifyDataSetChanged y tampoco funciona.

Este método es para exportar:

```
public void exportarRegistros() {
    String estadoSD = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (estadoSD.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        try {
            lista = ServicioParqueos.getInstance(this).cargarDatosParqueo();
            File archivo = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), nombreArchivo);
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archivo));
            if (lista != null) {
                output.writeObject(lista);
            }
            output.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al cargar el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("clase no encontrada", e.getMessage());
        }
    } else if (estadoSD.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Memoria montada como SOLO LECTURA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No se puede acceder al tarjeta SD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

El dialogo exportar:

```
public AlertDialog dialogoExportar() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[2];
    items[0] = getResources().getString(R.string.dilog_exp_sin);
    items[1] = getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_exp_con);
    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_exp_titulo)).
            setSingleChoiceItems(items, UNSELECTED, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int posicion) {
                    selected = posicion;
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int posicion) {
                    if (selected != UNSELECTED) {
                        switch (selected) {
                            case 0:
                                exportarRegistros(); //funcion exportar registros al almacenamiento externo
                                adapterListener.onClickListener(true);// interfaz que se implementa en el adapter, aca me da error nullPointException

           // elimina el archivo de la memoria interna
                             /* try {
                                  ServicioParqueos.getInstance(context).eliminarDatos();


                                   Toast.makeText(ParkingActivity.this, "Regisros exportados con exito\n" +
                                           "Se eliminaron los registros del almacenamiento interno", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(ParkingActivity.this, "No se pudo eliminar el registro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                    Log.e("clase no encontrada", e.getMessage());
                                }*/ 

                                break;

                            case 1:
                                exportarRegistros();
                                Toast.makeText(ParkingActivity.this, "Regisros exportados con exito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

El adapter:

```
public class AdaptadorParqueos extends ArrayAdapter<Parqueos> implements ParkingActivity.AdapterListener {

AdaptadorParqueos adapter;

public AdaptadorParqueos(Context context, List<Parqueos> objets) {
    super(context, R.layout.grid_template, objets);

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View item = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_template, null);
    }

    TextView textMatricula = item.findViewById(R.id.txt_matricula);
    TextView textIdUser = item.findViewById(R.id.txt_idCliente);
    textMatricula.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position)).getTxtMatricula());
    textIdUser.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position)).getTxtIdCliente());
    item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setMessage("Desea eliminar el regisro ?")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            try {
                                ServicioParqueos.getInstance(getContext()).eliminar(getItem(position));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error al actualizar el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                Log.e("ClassNotFound", e.getMessage());
                            }
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).create().show();
        }
    });

    return item;
}

@Override
public void onClickListener(boolean eliminar) {
    if (eliminar) {
        adapter.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}